# Changing the color and style of specific words in a sentence (Word output in Quarto R)

Tags: r, cpu-word, quarto

I want to output a Word document through `R` `quarto`. But I don't want have the phrases in my Word document all "plain". Ideally, I would like to be able to emphasize the text (i.e, convert to **bold** style) and/or change the color.

```
---
title: "Title"
format: 
  docx:
    reference-doc: custom-reference-doc.docx
editor: visual
number-sections: false
execute: 
  echo: false
  warning: false
  error: false
mainfont: Time New Roman
sansfont: Times New Roman
---
```

```
    
library(officer)
library(dplyr)

text <- "I want this phrase in different styles and colors."

doc <- read_docx("custom-reference-doc_10.docx")
doc <- body_add_par(doc, value = text, style = "First Paragraph")

print(doc, target = "file.docx")
```

So with this code, I was hoping to view a phrase like the one bellow, in the `file.docx`.

[image: example]

The closest thing I found to obtain this, was with the package `ReporteRs` (with functions like `addParagraph`). But this package is no longer available for my version of `R`.

Does anyone have an alternative? Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm also struggling with this -- did you find an answer to our question?

Comment: Thank you for the reminder! Luckily, yes I did. I'll provide an answer bellow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually very simple through `fp_text`and `f_par` functions.
If you are going to type a lot of text, I suggest saving the styles you want to apply to your texts.
For example:

```
normal <- fp_text(bold = FALSE, font.size = 16, font.family = "Times New Roman") # the default color is black, as expected
bold <- fp_text(bold = TRUE, font.size = 16, font.family = "Times New Roman")
blue_bold <- fp_text(bold = TRUE, font.size = 16, font.family = "Times New Roman", color = "lightblue")
```

There are other specifications to add to the `fp_text` function, I suggest looking into it.
And then applying it to your sentence:

```
sentence <- fpar(ftext("I want this phrase in different ", prop = normal),
                 ftext(" styles ", prop = bold),
                 ftext("and", prop = normal),
                 ftext(" colors", prop = blue_bold),
                 ftext(".", prop = normal))
```

Not forgetting to add it and print the word document:

```
doc <- body_add_fpar(doc, sentence, style = "First Paragraph")
print(doc, target = "file.docx")
```

In the output it appears as:
[image: output_phrase]

Hope I can help others!