.css to specify math font using Quarto and knitting to HTML
I'm using .css file to style my R Quarto reports to render using the font Aktiv Grotesk. However, when I insert an equation I'd like to use a different font because the square root symbol renders like this:

This is my Quarto file:
---
format: 
  html:
    css: styles2.css
---

Tilt magnitude is calculated using $Mag = \sqrt{N^{2} + W^{2}}$.

This is my styles2.css file:
p {
  font-size: 11pt;
  font-family: 'Aktiv Grotesk';
  color:black

}
* {
  font-family: 'Aktiv Grotesk', Times, serif ;
}

Is there a .css command that will allow me to style the equation font separately? If not, how can I achieve a textbook equation without changing the report font?

Does this help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75717165/changing-the-color-and-style-of-specific-words-in-a-sentence-word-output-in-qua

Thanks for the link. The answers there use fp_text and f_par functions from the officer package. That package is used when rendering to MS Word documents. I'm looking for a solution when rendering in HTML.

The relevant css selectors which you could use are

Inline math: span.math.inline or, for excluding things, span:not(.math.inline),
Display math: span.math.display or, for excluding things, span:not(.math.display).

In your example, we could disable the css with the special font and set a separate color like this:
document.qmd
---
format: 
  html:
    css: styles2.css
---

Tilt magnitude is calculated using $Mag = \sqrt{N^{2} + W^{2}}$.

styles2.css
p, span:not(.math.inline) {
    font-size: 11pt;
    font-family: 'Aktiv Grotesk';
    color:black
}

span:not(.math.inline) {
    font-family: 'Aktiv Grotesk', Times, serif ;
}

span.math.inline {
    color: red;
}


